# Cosmos DB Emulator won't start on Windows 10

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I’m recieving this error when I try to start Cosmos Emulator 2.7.2.0:

[image: Error]

[image: eventlog]

Tried it on a fresh win10 machine, and it's working here. Any ideas on what might course this?

I tried all the  [suggestions in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator#troubleshooting).

Looking at the etl file didn't give my anything either.

It's the first time I try to install it on my machine.

-- UPDATE --

I opened the dmp file, and found this:

```
Loading Dump File [C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\CrashDumps\Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.StartupEntryPoint.exe(1).12596.dmp]
User Mini Dump File: Only registers, stack and portions of memory are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 18363 MP (12 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: SingleUserTS
18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Mon Jan 20 09:35:26.000 2020 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 0 days 0:00:02.000
................................................................
..................................
This dump file has an exception of interest stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
(3134.41b0): Unknown exception - code c000000d (first/second chance not available)
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14:
00007ff9`562fcc14 c3              ret
0:000> .ecxr
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000003629dfd270
rdx=00000000e6bc7d4e rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=000000006748b0ec rsp=0000003629dfd190 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=000001ba53134730  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000026
r11=000001ba6d7662e0 r12=0000000000000004 r13=000001ba6d7974d0
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
msvcr80!_invalid_parameter+0x6c:
00000000`6748b0ec 488d4c2440      lea     rcx,[rsp+40h]
```

Seems like something is wrong with my version of msvcr80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally got it working!**

By using WinDbg and opening the dmp files %LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps, I found out that a dll called perf-MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS-sqlctr10.1.2531.0.dll was the root cause.
By deleting this in the %WINDIR%\System32 the error was "fixed" and I can now run the emulator.

Comment: How did you find that thew dll file was the root cause?

Answer (score 3):

This may be caused by corrupted performance counters on your machine.

To fix your performance counters try the following.

- Open cmd as administrator
- Run "lodctr /R" (must use capital R)

If this doesn't work, see this link here that shows other options to reset your counters. Older article but works the same on Windows 10.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf/possible-performance-counter-problem-on-win10/3a5c22cb-1425-4d26-99e7-4ec46940b9a1

btw, one more option here, is to run the emulator in a Docker container. The docs on that are in that article you referenced in your question.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly it didn’t help.
Thought about running it in docker but would be nice to get this to work. :)

Comment: This worked for me, but i neede to run the command twice :/

Comment: There is a article about this approach here: https://azurelessons.com/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-not-working/

Answer (score 3):

For me this confusing error message simply meant that I needed to **use another port**! Or fix problems with the default 8081 one (read update 2 way below).

Here's the text of the error so that it's searchable:

> Error: multiple attempts to restart one of the Azure Cosmos Emulator
> processes were detected. The emulator will shutdown. If the problem
> persist please try uninstalling the Azure Cosmos Emulator, remove the
> CosmosDBEmulator directory from your %%LOCALAPPDATA%% and reinstall.
> You can also reach out to the Azure Cosmos team using the 'Feedback'
> link in the Data Explorer browser window.

#### Details:

In my case this happened by itself after Windows 10 updated 2004. I swear something breaks in Cosmos DB emulator every feature update!

For me there were no crash dumps and rebuilding performance counters didn't help. In the Event Viewer for System I've noticed this error A LOT:

`Unable to bind to the underlying transport for 127.0.0.1:8081. The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.  The data field contains the error number.`

No solutions for this error helped, so I first used `netstat -ao` to see if any program is already listening at 8081. Nope.

Then I used the "Port listener" utility from the www, and it turned out it can't listen to 8081 either, not even under admin rights!

Since I couldn't fix this 8081 problem at all & turning off Windows Firewall didn't help, I simply started the Cosmos DB emulator at a different port and it worked!

`C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator>Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /Port=18001`

If you've configured cosmos db to be started automatically on system startup, make sure to update that script as well.

In my case this cmdline got me into the Data explorer, but it wasn't actually working. The "Explorer" part of it was "fetching offers" infinitely. I had to again uninstall Cosmos DB emulator, clean this folder: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CosmosDBEmulator`, reboot, install again without starting at 8081, and only start at the new port.

Cosmos DB devs, you're awesome people, but this is too much hassle. And if you can't use the port just say so, you don't have to be cryptic!

**UPDATE**:
This worked, but I forgot to update the start up script to use the new port, and noticed that after one more reboot the cosmos db started on 8081 without issues. What??! But it wasn't just any old reboot - I already did several of them before and they didn't help. This reboot may have been special in that it came after Windows found one more update (kb4576478), probably realizing it's now needed since I'm at version 2004, installed it, and THAT reboot (or the kb4576478 update specifically) fixed the 8081 problem, whatever it was. Yikes!

**UPDATE 2**:
Had another port-related problem with another tool. Ugh. Found this solution (see "General workaround") https://superuser.com/a/1568476/251491 This page's accepted answer also mentions the magic of multiple reboots.